# Show all Available Bookable Product in "WooCommerce Bookings" extension

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[User select date, time and then search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDwk2.png)

[image]

After click "Search Availability", it is needs to show all the available product within the provided date and time slot. 
Using "WooCommerce Bookings" extension, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have customized both WooCommerce  & Booking Extension:

## To save bookable product :

```
woocommerce-bookings/includes/class-wc-bookings-admin.php
```

## Method executes saving :

```
save_product_data( $post_id ) at line 434
```

## File for searching listing page:

```
woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php
```

## Skip loading boooking:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/includes/booking-form/class-wc-booking-form.php
```

## skip loading date time:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/assets/js/booking-form.js

/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/booking.php
```

I tried to solve it as database driven solution first but data seems like unstructured. Also without identifying the Property and Method at the Code, you won't be able to make any customization. Doing customization the plugin and extension is easy but he hard part is understand the code structure and flow. Once you get it, you may do any level of customization. 
There are lots of files (.PHP,JS) you needs to check but I have made it narrow for you. You only check the mentioned file above and can do your modification most of the case.